# Focus DOM above overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

Am trying to make a whole screen overlay, and just pop a single DOM above it, it is kind of web game tutorial which tell the user which button he should press.

[image]

Like the above image illustrate, am trying to hide everything under the overlay and only pop the red icon above it

**What I've tried so far**

I've added a div directly under the body tag (this will be the overlay) that will have a z-index greater that other elements in the page, and only the focused DOM will have a greater z-index than the overlay

**Issue**

This didn't work because am having a `translate` for the `opts-container` element, and remove this style is not an option for me because am using it all over the elements.

**code (to illustrate)**

```js
$("#veil").hide();
$('.icons-group-s div').on('mouseenter',function(){
  console.log("hovered");
    $("#veil").show();
    })
    
    $("#veil").on('mouseleave', function(){
    console.log("hide");
    $("#veil").hide();
      });
```

```css
#opts-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform:translateX(50px)
}

#veil {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

.icons-group-s {
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.icons-group-s div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#policy {
  z-index: 102;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="veil">

    </div>

    <div id="opts-container" class="hor menu-bottom">
        <div class="icons-group-s">
            <div id="policy" class="text-under-icon"></div>
            <div id="military" class="text-under-icon" ></div>
            <div id="socity" class="text-under-icon"></div>
            <div id="eco" class="text-under-icon" ></div>
            <div id="inventory" class="text-under-icon" ></div>
         
        </div>
    </div>
```

**possible solutions in my mind**

1- make clipped overlay

2- clone the focused object to be inside the veil div

3- focus the parent of the object and reduce opacity of child elements (workaround)

how can I pop an element over an overlay even if it has a `transform` style ?

maybe a hack around ?

Comment: you need position to be able to use z-index; add position:relative to your element and it will work

Comment: DOM stands for Document Object Model. There aren't multiple DOMs, it's just a thing that lets you interact with the markup of the page in object form. The word you're looking for is "element".

Comment: @TemaniAfif There was more to the question that just z-indexes. There's also the issue of having one element on top of the other blocking the events from getting triggered. You closed the question before I could post the answer. I think it should be reopened.

Comment: @Mason the question is: *am trying to hide everything under the overlay and only pop the red icon above it* then he showed where he failed and the issue was the miss of position:relative. If there is more than that then the question need to be edited to highlight that correcting the position isn't the only fix.

Comment: I can't post it as an answer but here is how I'd do it https://jsfiddle.net/ct7oyf2e/

Comment: @TemaniAfif Look like I forgot to add ``transform:translateX()`` to my snippet, it is not related to the other question you mentioned as I've added ``position:relative`` but it didn't work, please check the snippet again

Comment: I add two others duplicate related to the transform. If you cannot remove it then it's dead, you can do nothing because transform will create a stacking context and all its content will fall inside and you have no way to move only one element above another one from the outside of the stacking context

Comment: @TemaniAfif I can't remove the transformation because it is a game and I'm using this transformation all over the elements, there got to be a hack to simulate this overlay, please open the question and let people share their knowledge, perhaps someone has a hack !

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've also edit the question to point out to the real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a big box-shadow on the element instead of an overlay:

```css
#opts-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform:translateX(50px)
}


.icons-group-s {
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.icons-group-s div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

/* Make sure the stacking context is also on the top */
#opts-container:hover {
  z-index:9999;
}
/* make the element on the top and add a big shadow
   100vw + 100vh will make sure that you will cover all the screen
   Or use any other big value
*/
#opts-container:hover  #policy {
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 calc(100vw + 100vh) rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
    <div id="opts-container" class="hor menu-bottom">
        <div class="icons-group-s">
            <div id="policy" class="text-under-icon"></div>
            <div id="military" class="text-under-icon" ></div>
            <div id="socity" class="text-under-icon"></div>
            <div id="eco" class="text-under-icon" ></div>
            <div id="inventory" class="text-under-icon" ></div>
         
        </div>
    </div>
```